# trying to see if a variable is included in a list in django

Tags: python, django, if-statement, tuples

I am trying to find if a selected country is in a list of tuples by using the following command in my view:

```
if second_tier.profile.country in COUNTRIES:
```

if I print second_tier.profile.country I have `CA`
and when I print COUNTRIES I get:

```
(('GB', 'United Kingdom'), ('AU', 'Australia'), ('AT', 'Austria'), ('BE', 'Belgium'), ('CA', 'Canada'), ('DK', 'Denmark'), ('FI', 'Finland'), ('FR', 'France'), ('DE', 'Germany'), ('HK', 'Hong Kong'), ('IE', 'Ireland'), ('IT', 'Italy'), ('LU', 'Luxembourg'), ('NL', 'Netherlands'), ('NZ', 'New Zealand'), ('NO', 'Norway'), ('PT', 'Portugal'), ('SG', 'Singapore'), ('ES', 'Spain'), ('SE', 'Sweden'), ('CH', 'Switzerland'), ('US', 'United States'))
```

So the if statement is supposed to return True, however it comes back as False.

Comment: So you're comparing string to tuple, not string to string, that's why.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: `if second_tier.profile.country in [x for x, _ in COUNTRIES]:`

Comment: @RoadRunner, what is the difference between 'code' second_tier.profile.country in  [x[0] for x in COUNTRIES]: 'code' and your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently searching for a string in a tuple of tuples. You need to make sure `COUNTRIES` is all strings to make this work. You can use some simple list comprehensions to transform your nested tuples.

Using tuple unpacking:

```
COUNTRIES = [x, _ for x in COUNTRIES]
```

Using indexing:

```
COUNTRIES = [x[0] for x in COUNTRIES]
```

Which takes the first element(country) from each of the tuples and puts them in a list.

Then you can do:

```
if second_tier.profile.country in COUNTRIES:
```

and it will return `True`.

Alternatively you could just loop over `COUNTRIES` and match `second_tier.profile.country` explicitly:

```
for country, _ in COUNTRIES:
    if second_tier.profile.country == country:
        return True
```

You could also use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here:

```
any(second_tier.profile.country == x for x, _ in COUNTRIES)
```

Which returns `True` is *any* match was found.

**Note:** Since your just doing a simple lookup, you could convert the `COUNTRIES` to a *set*, which will allow a O(1) lookup instead of a O(N) lookup.

I also used `_` above to discard values that are not needed, such as the second item for each tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You have a tuple of tuples, then you need to iterate in COUNTRIES.

```
>>> for x in COUNTRIES:
...     if second_tier.profile.country in x:
...         print ("ok")
```